# Spring returns application/*+xml and not application/xml

Tags: xml, spring, api, rest, spring-mvc

I have a restful API that should return xml or json responses. The configuration is as follows:

```
<bean       class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="false" />
        <property name="mediaTypes">
            <map>
                <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
                <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultViews">
            <list>
                <bean
                        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
                        <property name="marshaller" ref="objectXmlMarshaller" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
</bean>
```

Alas, we get responses that are application/*+xml instead of application/xml. This causes chrome (or other browsers) to download the file instead of displaying it.

Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to specify response type explicitly using *"produces"* property of the *@RequestMapping* annotation. For example:

```
@RequestMapping(value="rest/somePath", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/xml")
public SomeObject restMethod(...necessary parametes...) {
    // Do necessary evaluation and return object.
}
```

[Here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-produces) you can find relevant part in spring reference documentation.

Comment: Thanks. This indeed works for one method. But what can be done if this is needed for the entire API with tens/ hundreds of methods?

Comment: This also will work properly if you annotate with @RequestMapping(...) whole controller class. But all mwthod level declaration will override class level declaration for produces property.

Comment: Also I think that you can try to override accept header for request to only "application/xml" (I think that this is possible using custom filter). This should force your application to return result in format that you need. But I have never done this and can't tell you how to do this exactly. This is just a thoughts.

Comment: thanks! The problem with annotating on method/class level is that you cannot keep it flexible to get back json or xml (and naturally it is cumbersome). Is this a bug with spring?

Comment: you can easily define few return (producible) formats. For example if you want to return application/xml or application/json you can specify produces froperty like: produces={"application/json", "application/xml"}.

Comment: it would be nicer to fix for all. but this is also good. thanks!